# Bokeh: Unable to render line from arrays stored in CDSView (jupyter notebook, CDS from Pandas dataframe)

Tags: bokeh

Edit for brevity:

I was trying to use CDSView to plot a line. The column source was a list of lists, and the CDSView would only pass one index from the list. However this does not work, even when using a single index in the nested list. The glyph compatibility depends on the source column format, and line cannot use a nested list even if the view it's being passed would be a single array. The multiline glyph must be used where the source column is a nested list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indices in `IndexFilter` represent indices within the columns of `ColumnDataSource`.

Try replacing `IndexFilter(indices=[0])` in your very first example with `IndexFilter(indices=[0, 1])`.

Comment: I did misunderstand that I was getting only the first x/y values in the first code example I give. But if the column is a list of arrays like the second example, is there a different way of getting that data? I think the issue I raise still stands, though I do see that the first example works with CDSView when I expand the indices.

Comment: @EugenePakomov:

Comment: @WesLudwig The question is, why do you need nested lists there? You're using `line` and `circle` glyphs, they don't work with lists of lists. AFAIK only `multi_line`, `multi_polygons`, and `patches` support lists of lists. And I just tested - views work fine in those cases.